# DoubleTapped Event not working on WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, event-handling, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `WebView` control which works fine, but when trying to attach the DoubleTapped Event to the control it doesn't seem to work when I physically go ahead and Double Tap on the web content in the emulator. Is there something that needs to be done?

My XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{StaticResource FeedEntryModel}">
    <WebView x:Name="feedEntry" IsHitTestVisible="True" DefaultBackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"  DoubleTapped="feedEntry_DoubleTapped" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHoldingEnabled="True" />
</Grid>
```

The Event Handler

```
private void feedEntry_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    feedEntry.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use the 'ScriptNotify' and inject some js to detect the internal double click. Use 'window.external.notify(obj);' to notify your external code. In this case obj is a json, it will allow me to notify multiple events. In your case you can simply add the 'ondblclick' event and call the function to notify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.document.ondblclick = function() {
    window.external.notify("dblclick");
}

private void OnScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == "dblclick")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because WebView content picks up the double tap. How about trying something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <WebView x:Name="feedEntry" Source="http://igrali.com" IsHitTestVisible="True" DefaultBackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHoldingEnabled="True" />
    <Grid DoubleTapped="feedEntry_DoubleTapped"
          Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's made it so that the double tap work but now the interaction with the WebView has stopped. I can't scroll or click links